# Accessing to UIView contents of a UIScrollView in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a function that creates an scrollview "personsScrollView".

```
@IBOutlet var personsScrollView: UIScrollView!
var personsScroll = UIView()
personsScroll = createPersonsScroll(CGSizeMake(60.0, 80.0), avatarCount: 10)

func createPersonsScroll(buttonSize:CGSize, avatarCount:Int) -> UIView {

    let padding = CGSizeMake(10, 10)
    let personButtonView = UIView()
    var buttonPosition = CGPointMake(padding.width * 0.5, padding.height)
    let buttonIncrement = buttonSize.width + padding.width

    personButtonView.frame.origin = CGPointMake(0,0)
    personButtonView.frame.size.width = (buttonSize.width + padding.width) * CGFloat(avatarCount+1)
    personButtonView.frame.size.height = (buttonSize.height +  2.0 * padding.height)

        for i in 0...(avatarCount-1)  {
            let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
            button.tag = i
            button.frame.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 55)
            button.frame.origin.x = buttonPosition.x
            button.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
            button.setImage(UIImage(named: self.person[button.tag].avatar), forState: .Normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: "addPersonSelected:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

            buttonPosition.x = buttonPosition.x + buttonIncrement

            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 60, 60, 15))
            label.text = self.person[i].name

            button.addSubview(label)
            personButtonView.addSubview(button)
        }
    }

    personsScrollView.contentSize = personButtonView.frame.size
    personsScrollView.addSubview(personButtonView)

    return personButtonView
}
```

This function creates a UIView "personButtonView" that will contain the 10 UIbuttons "button", and each button has a different image.
My questions is, outside of the code, in ViewDidLoad(), how do I access for example to the image of the 2nd button to replace only that image? Or how to access to the label of the 4th button to change its text?

I would appreciate your help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this code, a hierarchy of views and subviews is being created. If you want a clean way to access these then you can simply create UIView subclasses to encapsulate your content.

To do this, refactor your code in `createPersonsScroll` into initializers. I can see several UIButton views being created, so you can define an `AvatarButton` class to encapsulate those, and probably also a `PersonView` class for its parent, with a property to access its content.

The idea is that you could then replace

```
personsScroll = createPersonsScroll(buttonSize: CGSizeMake(60.0, 80.0), avatarCount: 10)
```

with for example:

```
personView = PersonView(CGSizeMake(60.0, 80.0), avatarCount: 10)
// ...
personView.avatarButtons[2].image = myImage
personView.avatarButtons[4].text = myString
```

Comment: That's a good answer however I was wondering the way to access without having to do a custom class

Comment: I just noticed I misunderstood the question slightly, you have several buttons. The answer is the same though: encapsulation.